# Laravel get record with date greater than today

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've got a table that has some event with dates and this table has columns `from_date` `to_date`. I want to pick only those records from DB that belong to that gap. However, I'm not even able to pick those where `to_date` is greater than `today`.

Here's what I'm trying

```
$date = today()->format('Y-m-d')
Action::where('to_date', '<=', $date)->get()
```

And here's what I get

```
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3211
     all: [
       App\Action {#3217
         id: 9,
         name: "Знижка 10%",
         from_date: "2018-09-19",
         to_date: "2018-09-21",
         image_path: "actions/September2018/8AUigc8LFZnqyANy7k7J.jpg",
         created_at: "2018-09-25 16:50:00",
         updated_at: "2018-09-25 16:50:57",
         infinite: 0,
       },
       App\Action {#3201
         id: 10,
         name: "Не должно бить відно",
         from_date: "2016-09-14",
         to_date: "2016-09-22",
         image_path: "actions/September2018/8QVS0uPI4S48kWg3ltza.jpg",
         created_at: "2018-09-25 17:32:08",
         updated_at: "2018-09-25 17:32:08",
         infinite: 0,
       },
     ],
   }
```

By some reason 2016 passes

Comment: You have it backwards. Right now you're saying where `to_date` is before today, not after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the query condition. Do this:

```
$date = today()->format('Y-m-d')
Action::where('to_date', '>=', $date)->get()
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. Actually I tried that, but only now I realize that I just had no events that satisfy the condition

Answer (score 0):

in my case this is worked:

```
Action::whereDate('to_date', '>', Carbon::now())->get();
```